# What kind of array is returned when calling Array() as a constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Why doesn't Array(42) work with an iterator, while Array(42).fill() does?

Answer (score -2):

`Array(42)` doesn't actually populate the array. `Array(42).fill()` creates elements with a static value. **Even if you don't pass a value to `.fill()`, the array will create the elements for each indicie.** Those elements will have an actual value of `undefined`, but the elements will exist.

You can't iterate over an empty array, but you can iterate over one that is populated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: Axel Rauschmayer wrote an excellent blog post about the difference between sparse and dense arrays: http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html

Comment: @JonKoops Not sure that this is exactly relevant to this issue.

Comment: It is relevant. `Array(42)` is a sparse array and `Array(42).fill()` is a dense array. It also explains that sparse arrays cannot be iterated upon.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make the connection that `.fill()` creates a dense array. It doesn't talk about `.fill()` at all, so someone questioning why `.fill()` makes a difference won't get any information about that question from that post.

Comment: OPs question is about why some parts of an array are iterable and some are not. And to answer that question you must first know the difference between a sparse and dense array.

Comment: OPs question is about the difference between Array and Array.fill()

Comment: Which is the difference between a sparse and a dense array.

Comment: `.fill()` is just a way of mapping `undefined` to the slots -- the more important question is what is the nature of those slots before they are filled...

Comment: I also find that article a bit lacking of detail -- what is the nature of the said "holes"?